# ACHI drivers for Windows 8.1 with AMD

Tags: drivers, ssd, windows-8.1, ahci

I just installed a Samsung EVO 840 SSD and Windows 8.1 Pro in my PC with M5A99X EVO (chipset AMD 990X/SB950) motherboard.

The SSD is installed in SATA 3 socket using a sata3 wire. The AHCI mode is ON in the BIOS. I configured the AHCI controller and now device administrator looks like this:

[image: Device administrator]

All works, but the speed of the SSD is very slow (like a HDD). Samsung magician doesn't recognize either the SATA mode or the AHCI. I tried to install more drivers, but the operating system broke and I need to reinstall Windows.

I tried many things from the internet, but nothing worked:

- Modify Windows Registry
- Use compatibility mode
- Modify the AMD drivers and install it unsigned

CrystalDiskMark benchmark:

[image]

Comment: could you post the SSD benchmarks results obtained using [CrystalDiskMark](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskMark/index-e.html) in here

Comment: @Vinayak there is the benchmark. I think they aren't as good as the should be....

Comment: post a picture of AS SSD Benchmark: http://alex-is.de/PHP/fusion/downloads.php?download_id=9

Comment: Also make sure your [SSD firmware is upgraded](https://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/samsungssd/downloads.html) to the latest version available.

Comment: Please [update your motherboard BIOS](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M5A99X_EVO/HelpDesk_Download/) to the latest version as well

Comment: If possible provide a [Speccy hardware report](https://www.piriform.com/docs/speccy/using-speccy/publishing-a-speccy-profile-to-the-web) as well

Comment: Please [read this forum post](http://www.thessdreview.com/Forums/priority-help-and-support/3799-asus-m5a99x-evo-rev-1-samsung-840-evo.html) and see of you have the same hardware as that guy and if you do, have you installed the [JMicron JMB36X SATA controller driver](http://www.techspot.com/drivers/driver/file/information/17342/)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem...

I decided to start from the begining, so I got the motherboard's user guide and started to read.

The guys of asus put a big sata 6gb text next to sata2 port, so I connect the SSD in the wrong  port... my fault, sorry.

Now, I have this benchmarks:

[image: CrystalDiskMark benchmark]

They still not being as good as they should, but I think this is because of performance configuration.

Finally, I must say that when I change the port, windows doesn't boot. It was solved by itself removing all installed programs without asking...

Again, **thank you.**

Edit: Device controllers:

[image: Device controllers]

Comment: By the way, from the looks of it, some controllers aren’t running in AHCI mode at all, otherwise the “Standard PCI IDE controller” entries wouldn’t be there.

Comment: I'll try to install ASUS drivers again and see what happen.

Comment: Drivers won't help. This is something you have to configure in the firmware setup. It's most likely the slower extra controller, so don't worry about it too much.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. At last, what do you think about current benchmark?

Comment: Read speeds look fine, can’t say anything about write speeds though, because I don’t have this SSD myself. You could also try AS SSD Benchmark, it shows the driver used to access the disk.